# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core parsing error

Tags: dynamic-linq

I have a simple class with one int property called Int:

```
public class TestObject
    {
        public int Int { get; set; }
    }
```

and wherePredicate "Int >= 90"

When I trying to use it with a IQueryable.Where(wherePredicate) the error occurs: System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: '.' or '(' or string literal expected

When I change wherePredicate to "It.Int >= 90" - works as expected.

Comment: Could you paste the exact code that fails? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int` is a reserved key-word.

Use a different Property name:

```
void Main()
{
    var l = new List<TestObject>();
    var q = l.AsQueryable();
    var result = q.Where("X >= 90");

    result.Dump(); // LINQPad
}

public class TestObject
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not accept because there is no such action on my user interface or I'm missing something?

Comment: When you are logged in, you can just click the (v) button on the left side of this answer.